# Override "kubernetes.io/hostname" on AWS EKS node using terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I'm trying to deploy an AWS environment using terraform. The EC2 instances and the cluster is created fine, but it fails when trying to join the instances with the cluster.

```
Error: error waiting for EKS Node Group (env-dev:node_1) to create: unexpected state 'CREATE_FAILED', wanted target 'ACTIVE'. last error: 1 error occurred:
* i-022a2d319d457ab83, i-0374c9efbb32b1f0f, i-05b42da747ca0c8cd, i-08439b352ff4bcc5f, i-0d286addbf2eedd2a, i-0dc6f1bd12b372427, i-0ed373f52f9e27510: NodeCreationFailure: Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster
```

According to CloudWatch, this is where it fails

```
"responseObject": {
    "kind": "Status",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "Node \"ip-10-206-68-167.eu-west-1.compute.internal\" is invalid: metadata.labels: Invalid value: \"ip-10-206-68-167.xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx.eu-west-1.a\": must be no more than 63 characters",
    "reason": "Invalid",
    "details": {
        "name": "ip-10-206-68-167.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
        "kind": "Node",
        "causes": [
            {
                "reason": "FieldValueInvalid",
                "message": "Invalid value: \"ip-10-206-68-167.xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx.eu-west-1.a\": must be no more than 63 characters",
                "field": "metadata.labels"
            }
        ]
    },
    "code": 422
}
```

Is there any way to override the hostname using terraform?

EDIT:

Snippet of the terraform:

```
variable "db_subnet_ids" { default = ["subnet-04f6e659f2b2851f2", "subnet-0a42b2ec54b5aa143"] }

resource "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
 enabled_cluster_log_types = [
  "api",
  "audit",
  "authenticator",
  "controllerManager",
  "scheduler",
 ]
 name = "env-${var.suffix}"
 role_arn = aws_iam_role.eks_cluster_role.arn
 vpc_config {
  subnet_ids = var.db_subnet_ids
  security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.cluster_http.id, aws_security_group.cluster_https.id]
 }
  
 depends_on = [
  aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy,
  aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy,
  aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly,
 ]
}

resource "aws_eks_node_group" "cluster" {
 cluster_name = aws_eks_cluster.cluster.name
 node_group_name = "node_1"
 node_role_arn = aws_iam_role.eks_nodes_role.arn
 subnet_ids = var.db_subnet_ids
 scaling_config {
  desired_size = 7
  max_size = 7
  min_size = 7
 }
 ami_type = "AL2_x86_64"
 capacity_type = "ON_DEMAND"
 disk_size = 50
 instance_types = ["t3.large"]

 depends_on = [
  aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy,
  aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy,
  aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly,
 ]
}
```

The VPC is created manually, so the configuration is as so:

Subnet ID: subnet-04f6e659f2b2851f2
Name: xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-private-eu-west-1a
IPv4 CIDR: 10.206.68.160/28

Subnet ID: subnet-0a42b2ec54b5aa143
Name: xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-private-eu-west-1b
IPv4 CIDR: 10.206.68.176/28

And the VPC
Name: xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx
VIP ID: vpc-09a3e88350a018cbf
IPv4 CIDR: 10.206.68.160/27
DHCP options set ID: dopt-0ea3823bed3d5ff2c

DHCP options set
ID: dopt-0ea3823bed3d5ff2c
Name: xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx

Name later altered to: xxxx-xx-xxxx-xxxx (2nd word shortened)
Explanation in my answer below.

Comment: The problem is that the `label` inside of the `metadata` is longer than 63 characters. Can you post that part of the code to the question?

Comment: I've added the terraform snippet for the EKS cluster.

Comment: And what is inside `var.db_subnet_ids`? Would you mind adding that as well?

Comment: I've added the VPC details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is somewhat resolved. Not sure I'm a big fan of the solution, but it works.

So the node hostnames was created by appending

- IP address
- DHCP options set name of from the VPC
- Not exactly sure where "eu-west-1" and "a" derives from.
  Region of the VPC perhaps? And the "a" from the subnet?

which it ended up with something like:

> ip-10-206-68-167.xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx.eu-west-1.a

So by shortening the DHCP options set name, the hostnames was therefore shortened as well, and everything is working just fine.